Making a secret gist public using gh cli
I've accidentally created a gist as secret gist via the gh (GitHub) CLI.
I'd like to make this secret gist now public. What CLI command can I use for this? Or is this feature not available in the CLI (yet)?
I know I can open the gist in the browser and click on "make public" but that's tedious.
In case the cli doesn't support publication, is there a workaround using the Github API?

There is neither gh command, not GitHub API to relist a secret gist as public. The only automated solution to this problem is to recreate the gist
Here is an automated way to do it:
# Filename used when gist was originally created
file=my-gist.sh

# Find gist ID
id=$(gh gist list|grep $file|cut -f1)

# Capture gist content
gh gist view $id > $file

# Delete old gist
gh gist delete $id

# Create new public gist with the same content
gh gist create $file --public


So that "make public" button on the website has no equivalent not even in the API? Strange! Also, I just learned that secret gist are only secret to the extent that they aren't searchable/indexed. Anyone with the URL can actually find them

Yes, it is surprising. There are several UI actions  on github .com that do not have an equivalent published API.
